# Why $f(x)=|x|+x$ is surjective?

Tags: calculus, functions

Taking into account that the function is defined from a set $ℝ$ to a set $ℝ$, why is surjective if all the negative numbers of the co-domain are not images of $f(x)$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  When you typed subjective, did you mean surjective?

Comment: draw a graph....and it is not

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- for $x\ge 0 \implies f(x)=x+x=2x$
- for $x< 0 \implies f(x)=-x+x=0$

from here we can simply conclude both for the surjectivity and for the injectivity of the given function.